# Compare predicted values with true values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I've split my data into X_train, X_test, y_train, and y_test, and is trying to compare `y_pred` (my model's prediction of the `X_test` set) with the ground truth values, `y_test`.

```
# Splitting data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
model = LinearRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)

# Trying to predict X_test with the model            
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# How do I compare y_pred with the y_test? 
print(model.score(X_test,y_test))
```

What do I put as parameters in the `model.score( , )` to compare `y_pred` with the `y_test`?

Do I print the score of `X_test` and `y_test`? My code just doesn't seem right.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected output so we have a better idea of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Your parameters look correct as per the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score. Looking at the source code (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/d99b728b3a7952b2111cf5e0cb5d14f92c6f3a80/sklearn/base.py#L760) we can see that the `score` function calculates the predicted values itself: you don't need to supply them.

Comment: @slothrop sorry I'm just kinda confused though, what exactly does `score(X_test,y_test)` print out? Does that have any relation to my `y_pred` ?

Comment: `score(X_test,y_test)` returns "the coefficient of determination" in the words of the documentation, i.e. what is usually called the R^2. Since you already have `y_pred`, you could indeed alternatively choose to calculate R^2 yourself instead of calling `score`.

Comment: @slothrop thanks! is there a way to put `y_pred` in `score( , )`? since otherwise, how will `score` "know" about the `y_pred` values? thanks again!

Comment: Check the link to the source code in my earlier comment. See how the first thing the `score` method does is to call `self.predict(X)` in order to get the predicted y values?

Comment: @slothrop thank you! so  basically `score` automatically uses `model.predict(X_test)` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LinearRegression.score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score) works in the way you called it: you pass in an `X` and a corresponding `y`, which it scores against a prediction it does not share with you.

Accordingly,I recommend not using `model.score()`, because it's a bit of an opaque function. You never get to see the prediction, and you don't know what the metric is without referring to the docs (it depends on the model; in this case it's R<sup>2</sup>).

Better to make a prediction, import the metric you want, and compute it explicitly. For example to use [mean squared error](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html):

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

mean_square_error(y_pred, y_test)
```